# Remove large block of blank text in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

Hello I have a string in PHP

```
$string = "...................blah blah blah.................."
```

where the ......... are blank spaces (stackoverflow doesn't let me enter many blank spaces).

How do I remove this block of blank spaces before and after the "blah blah blah" text? "blah blah blah" is parsed data that changes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the function [trim](http://php.net/trim)().

```
$string = '..............bla bla bla........'; // where . represents space before and after
$string = trim($string);
```